# Show Android ProgressBar with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, mono

I am building an Android app through Xamarin/MonoTouch (so using C# rather than Java) and would like to display a ProgressBar while the app is communicating with the server. I have been attempting to do this using async, but I don't have a good understanding of how threading works, and I've been running into the same issue for the past few hours - the ProgressBar shows after my method call rather than before. My code is in the OnCreate() method, which I have also overridden to be async. Here it is:

```
        loginButton.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            progbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

            var userFetcher = new UserFetcher();
            var json = await userFetcher.FetchUserDetailsAsync(/*parameters*/);
            //the above method is async and returns a Task<JsonValue>
            ParseUserDetails(json); //another method I created

            progbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            //do some stuff using the parsed data
        };
```

The issue I'm running into is that the FetchUserDetailsAsync seems to be blocking my thread. I have been testing this by shutting the server off so that it takes a long response time (but even when I test stuff like Thread.Sleep(5000) I have the same issue). After the method has been called, it runs both `progbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;` and `progbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;` right after one another - I know this because when I comment out the Invisible part, the ProgressBar appears after my method got a "response" from the server. The compiler has also been giving me messages like "Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Like I said earlier, I'm not really experienced with threading, so it's very possible I'm just naively doing something wrong. Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

EDIT: Here is the source code for FetchUserDetailsAsync:

```
    public async Task<JsonValue> FetchUserDetailsAsync(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        string myBasicHeader = AuthenticationHelper.MakeHeader(username, password);

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + myBasicHeader);

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                    return jsonDoc;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                var response = e.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                if (response != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("HTTP Status Code: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No http status code available");
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like either FetchUserDetailsAsync or ParseUserDetails is blocking the UI thread. Because Task.Sleep(5000) is running synchronously. Try await Task.Delay(5000); in the line of FetchUserDetailsAsync to see if the progressbar show up. If it does, then you probably need to go into FetchUserDetailsAsync implementation to make sure it is implemented async

Comment: Very interesting. When I tried Task.Delay(), things worked as I want. I am looking into FetchUserDetailsAsync now to see what might be the issue

Comment: I spent some time looking at FetchUserDetailsAsync() and I can't really understand what might be its issue. It uses an async call to `await Task.Run()`. The other half of code is just catching exceptions and returning null if that's the case. Using `await Task.Yield()` actually gives the ProgressBar time to display, but it does not animate - as though FetchUserDetailsAsync() is somehow still running synchronously. I will post the source code for this data in the OP

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. I was calling `GetResponse()` instead of `GetResponseAsync()` in my FetchUserDetailsAsync method.